# Magento layout replace block with another block

Tags: php, magento, layout

I want to replace a block in the standard layout catalog.xml with one a custom type block.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
</block>
```

I want to replace the above standard with my **own custom block type below**, but using the same "name".

```
<block type="attributesasgroup/groupview" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="webguys/attributesasgroup/groupview.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
</block>
```

Can someone advise me the best way to do this? I don't know the XML actions and methods to use. Do i need to remove the previous block? unsetChild? IF i add a block with the same "name" and same parent, will overwrite the existing one with the same name?

Answer (score 2):

I will go through each of your doubt here.

*1. Whether I can replace the default block with my custom block as shown above ?*

Ofcourse you can. You can use your own block instead of default block with your above code

*2. What is the best way to do this ?*

I prefer usage of `local.xml` for this purpose. `local.xml` is a special layout file that will always processed at last by Magento. i e, the layout updates that are specified through this file will consider and applied at last, after consdered all other layout updating files. So this is an easy way to alter any layout changes. So include this file inside your theme's layout directory with specified layout changes.

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>

    <remove name="product.attributes" />

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="attributesasgroup/groupview" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="webguys/attributesasgroup/groupview.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

The layout that hold by our `local.xml` is so simple. First it removes the default block from layout structure. In order to use this, we used `remove` node for this. Then we added our own block to the content part.

Here it is important that your block should be defined at the backend side. If it is not defined, Magento will not understand which block that you are referencing to it, so that, magneto will not render the content inside your block. So make sure it is defined in backend. In the above case, in order to process your block correctly, Magento needs `Namespace_Modulename_Block_Groupview` to be defined at `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Block/Groupview.php` (where `Namespace_Modulename` stands for your custom module name,)

*3. IF i add a block with the same "name" and same parent, will overwrite the existing one with the same name?*

Of course you can give your block default block's name. **In magento, each and every block should have a unique name**. In order to obey this rule, we need to remove the default block first. This will allow us to use that block name in our own block. Otherwise Magento will *behave in bad way*.

**Note:** There are two actions that are applying to your blocks. They are `addToParentGroup` and `setTitle`. First one set your block to `detailed_info` group and the second one is using to set a title for your block.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like this?

```
<reference name="product.attributes">

  <action method="setTemplate">

     <template>webguys/attributesasgroup/groupview.phtml</template>

   </action>

     <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value>

</reference>
```

we just replace a new template for the instance of the block keeping everything the same attribute values like `name`, `as` and others

**Source**: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts#head-anatomy-of-a-layout